# Finding time complexity of recursive equation

Tags: algorithm

how to apply back substituion on following recursive equation to find time complexity:

`T(n)= 2 T(n/2) + (n/log n)`

where  `n` is input.

Comment: Look at [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).